# Action and parameters in dialogeflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

When I created A Parameter and I assigned it to te entity called @sys.unit-information-name,
I keep getting this warning: *The annotated text 'diabetes' in training phrase 'show me results on diabetes' does not correspond to entity type '@sys.unit-information-name'. And as a result my chatbot does not give me the right result, basically it will just keep asking the question under the Prompts under the Action and parameters.

If I remove this parameter it works. But I want to use the parameter & Entity

Any Help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is because you are explicitly creating  a parameter and adding the system entity @sys.unit-information-name. This entity is used to refer to information about units as per [system Entities documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/system-entities#units).

[image]

Since you are referring to a disease “diabetes” as per your expression “show me results on diabetes”,  this entity cannot be used to map diabetes or any other disease also. There is no system Entities for Diseases, so it's better that we create a custom entity defining most of the disease names.

When giving the training Phrases if the word matches with values defined in entity, then entity mapping for that word will be done and the response will be generated.

[image]